# HTML 5 DatePicker events not firing on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, django

Im trying to implement a date picker to update a graph with some information from a certain point in time. Using jquery ive tried onblur onchange and onkeyup but none of those events seem to be firing on either Mobile chrome or iOS safari.

I then tried **onblur=** with no success either.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong here?

```
  <div class="col-50 graph-date-select-container">
    <input id="graph-date-input" type="date" class="graph-date-select" style="-webkit-appearance: textfield; -moz-appearance: textfield; height: 20px; margin-top: -15px;" onblur="graphUpdate()"/>
  </div>


function graphUpdate() {
  alert("graphUpdate called.")
  var date = new Date($(this).val());

  var dateString = "" + date.getDay() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear();

  var url = "{% add_params request.get_full_path period='daily'%}" + "query_param=" + dateString
  window.location.href = url
};
```

Essentially all that needs to happen is that when the value in the input is changed (the user hides the date input pop up) the dat is passed as a param to the django template and the page reloads with the new information.

Comment: Please go through http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php

Comment: That does not tell me anything about why im having an issue.

Comment: But there they tell in which browsers that supports. So, you need to use plugin datepicker

Comment: I have checked on caniusethis and it is supported on the web browsers that i require it to work on but for some odd reason the events are not firing

Answer (score 0):

You should follow my code, it will works::

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-50 graph-date-select-container">
    <input id="graph-date-input" type="date" class="graph-date-select" style="-webkit-appearance: textfield; -moz-appearance: textfield; height: 20px;" onchange="graphUpdate(this.value)"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function graphUpdate(value) {
    var date = new Date(value);
    console.log(date);
    var dateString = "" + date.getDay() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear();

    var url = "{% add_params request.get_full_path period='daily'%}" + "query_param=" + dateString;
    window.location.href = url;
};
```

Remeber this will print the date you choose, rest of the code you need to change as you want.

=========================================================================

**UPDATED VERSION::**
Please try this one

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-50 graph-date-select-container">
    <input id="graph-date-input" type="date" class="graph-date-select" style="-webkit-appearance: textfield; -moz-appearance: textfield; height: 20px;"/>
</div>
<div id="testingDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.graph-date-select', function () {
        var date = new Date($(this).val());
        $('#testingDiv').html(date);
        alert(date); //first check date is alerting or not
        return false;
        var dateString = "" + date.getDay() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear();

        var url = "{% add_params request.get_full_path period='daily'%}" + "query_param=" + dateString;
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, however nothing is happening on mobile iOS safari or Mobile Chrome when i try using your code.

Comment: Yes the datepicker is showing but the event listener does not fire once i have selected a date and hit done.

Comment: Which version of jQuery library are you using?

Comment: Im using v2.1.4 jquery